# Return value sheet using index and match formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to make a return value sheet using index and match formula. it's working when I showed a specific cell (check my first formula)

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$7,MATCH(0,IF(($E$2=$A$1:$A$7)*($F$2=$B$1:$B$7),COUNTIF($G$1:$G2,$C$1:$C$7),""),0))
```

but when I try to use find a text value in this selected cell it's not working (Check my second formula).

```
 =INDEX($C$1:$C$7,MATCH(0,IF(($E$2=$A$1:$A$7)*("*C*"=$B$1:$B$7),COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$C$1:$C$7),""),0))
```

So please advise us if you have any solution of this formula or any other option to show same results

[image: SPREAD SHEET].

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use SEARCH or FIND:

```
 =INDEX($C$1:$C$7,MATCH(0,IF(($E$2=$A$1:$A$7)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",$B$1:$B$7))),COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$C$1:$C$7),""),0))
```

Comment: Yes nice, Thanks

Comment: How can I use here third criteria/match same using search text value?